# Obtain the last sample

Tags: bash, awk

I need to use awk form a variable with this sintaxis [Subrack=xxx,Slot=x]:[sample]. How can I do to obtain only the latest sample of every CPU from below output using awk?

```
Time  Object               The_average_processor_load_of_a_board_in_percent
22:30 Subrack=MAIN,Slot=1                                                 1
22:30 Subrack=MAIN,Slot=12                                               21
22:30 Subrack=MSE1,Slot=1                                                 1
22:30 Subrack=MSE1,Slot=10                                                3
22:30 Subrack=MSE1,Slot=11                                                3
22:30 Subrack=MSE2,Slot=1                                                 1
22:30 Subrack=MSE2,Slot=10                                                1
22:45 Subrack=MAIN,Slot=1                                                 1
22:45 Subrack=MAIN,Slot=12                                               20
22:45 Subrack=MSE1,Slot=1                                                 1
22:45 Subrack=MSE1,Slot=10                                                3
22:30 Subrack=MSE1,Slot=11                                                2
22:45 Subrack=MSE2,Slot=1                                                 1
22:45 Subrack=MSE2,Slot=10                                                1
```

I tried the following code

```
awk '!seen[$0]++ {lines[i++]=$0} END {for (i in lines) if (seen[lines[i]]==1) print lines[i]}' {print} {++seen[$0]}'
```

without obtaining the desired results.

The posted output was cut, the complete one can view here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4d45x6m1701lpvz/complete_output.txt?dl=0

Comment: You have an extra quote -- notice the syntax highlighting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrays to hold the time and sample for each CPU. If the time of the current row is higher than the saved time for that CPU, you replace them.

```
awk '$0 > time[$2] { time[$2] = $1; sample[$2] = $3; }
     END { for (cpu in sample) printf("[%s]:[%d]\n", cpu, sample[cpu]) }'
```

Comment: How can use it for every CPU?                                                                    ` [root@lnxni075 ~]# awk '$0 > time[$1] { time[$1] = $0; sample[$1] = $3; } END { for (cpu in sample) printf("[%s]:[%d]\n", cpu, sample[cpu]) }' /tmp/test.log `
[22:30]:[1]
[22:45]:[1]

Comment: I made a mistake in column numbers, should be fixed now. Column 2 is the CPU, right? So this stores the sample and timestamp for each CPU.

Comment: Yes, column 2 is the CPU

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==1 { print $2, "latest"; next }
{ latest[$2] = $3 }
END { for (cpu in latest) print cpu, latest[cpu] }

$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -t
Object                latest
Subrack=MAIN,Slot=12  20
Subrack=MSE2,Slot=10  1
Subrack=MSE1,Slot=10  3
Subrack=MSE1,Slot=11  2
Subrack=MAIN,Slot=1   1
Subrack=MSE2,Slot=1   1
Subrack=MSE1,Slot=1   1
```